# paint in red Condition cell value in gridview - android

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a gridview that contain cells with numbers

```
GridView gridView;
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;
    static final String[] numbers = new String[] { 
            "1", "2", "3", "4", "5",
            "6", "7", "8", "9", "10",
            "11", "12", "13", "14", "15",
            "16", "17", "18", "19", "20",
            "21", "22", "23", "24", "25",
            "26", "27","28","29"
            };

gridView = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridview);
        adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, numbers);
        gridView.setAdapter(adapter);
        gridView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v,
                int position, long id) {
                //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),((TextView) v).getText(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                v.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
            }
        });
```

how can i run on this grid, and paint in red every value cell that is >10

thanks

Comment: I think need to write custom adapter.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use custom adapter for this and for custom adapter you can create one layout which contains one relativeLayout and one textView inside relativeLayout .
Than in adapter you can set condition like :

```
if(numbers[position] > 10 ){

    relativeLayout.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);

}
```